# issue on uninstalling @azure/msal-angular from Angular project. BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules

Tags: angular, msal-angular

My project was using @azure/msal-angular. I uninstalled the library and removed all the related imports. On uninstalling the library my build and ng s is failing and showing following error. Kindly help on this

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:

- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
- install 'util'
  If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
  resolve.fallback: { "util": false }`

Answer (score 1):

You need to install util

> **npm i util**

in you project, that should resolve the issue
If you have custom webpack.config file then add

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
      fallback: {
        util: require.resolve("util/")
      }
  }
};
```

after updating this if you are still getting error like
**Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined utill.js**

Please add below to polyfill.ts file

```
(window as any).process = { env: { DEBUG: undefined }, };
```